# how to create a singleton in swift with init variables

Tags: swift, singleton

I am trying to create a singleton class in swift but I am getting an error 
"cannot create a single-element tuple with an element label"

i am not getting it.

```
class GroupObject {
// we want the group object to be a singleton


var name: String
var id: Int
var groupJsonObject: JSON

init(groupJsonObject: JSON){
    self.groupJsonObject = groupJsonObject
    self.id = groupJsonObject["id"].int!
    self.name = groupJsonObject["name"].string!
}


class var sharedInstance : GroupObject {
    struct Static {
        static let instance : GroupObject = GroupObject(groupJsonObject: JSON) // this is the problem line.
    }
    return Static.instance

}


}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of having `var groupJsonObject: JSON` if you're instantiating your class with `groupJsonObject`?

Comment: Where is `JSON` coming from in the problem line? Were you expecting it to come from an *instance* of `GroupObject`? When referencing a class variable, there *are* no accessible properties.

Comment: I am confused, you want to create a singleton but at the same time you are using a constructor?

Comment: Yes, this is very confusing. Also, structs are immutable and classes are mutable, you probably don't want to put a struct inside of a class here.

Comment: ok, maybe this is not the way I want to handle this. I basically want to instantiate a class for the life of the app. I need a model that will hold my users info. The above code is a simplified version of it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you cannot pass a parameter to the singleton. Your singleton implementation doesn't know to what `JSON` refers.

If you want this to be a singleton, you'd have to initialize the `groupJsonObject` separately from the initialization of the shared instance. For example:

```
class GroupObject {
    var name: String!
    var id: Int!

    var groupJsonObject: JSON! {
        didSet {
            id = groupJsonObject["id"].int!
            name = groupJsonObject["name"].string!
        }
    }

    static let sharedInstance = GroupObject()   // btw, this is a more concise syntax for declaring a singleton
}
```

And then, when you want to initialize those properties, you could do:

```
GroupObject.sharedInstance.groupJsonObject = json
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Now, by initializing the properties, do you mean this is how I instantiate the class?

Comment: @skrite - What I mean is that in your original `struct Static` you appear to attempt to instantiate a `GroupObject`, passing some `JSON` (which would call your initializer that would initialize your properties). But since you can't do that, in the code in my question, you call `GroupObject.sharedInstance` (which the first time you call it will instantiate a `GroupObject` singleton instance),. Having done that, you can now set `groupJsonObject`. So, it's two separate steps.

Comment: I see. Thanks very much. So i still create it with let group = GroupObject() and then use the GroupObject.sharedInstance.groupJsonObject = json to initialize the values, or would I use group.sharedInstance....

Comment: The `GroupObject.sharedInstance.groupJsonObject = json` is equivalent to `let group = GroupObject.sharedInstance` (which instantiates the singleton, if you haven't already) followed by `group.groupJsonObject = json` (which sets its property). It's just a more concise way of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If your "singleton" is supposed to hold some data passed to it on instantiation, how will it get that data? Where/when is it available?

I think you don't actually want a singleton at all; you want an instance created with your JSON data to be accessible from different points in your application. In that case, pick some "master controller", create it there, then pass it along to other controllers as needed.

Comment: This sounds like the best idea. Thanks for your help.